# Object remains on stage after removeChild() in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am using `removeChild()` to remove a MovieClip. And via tests, I can confirm that it's working fine ( `stage.contains(mc)` returns `false` ). But the MovieClip still does not seem to be removed, as if the stage is not updated correctly.

Please help me on this,
thanks,
V.

Comment: Please show some code, otherwise it is impossible to tell what went wrong.

Comment: yes need snippets, prob you are missing refferences.

Comment: What do you mean by "the MovieClip still does not seem to be removed"? Is it still visible on the stage, or do you mean that it is still processing actions? Removing something from the stage does only that, it will not destroy the object.

Comment: @shanethehat From what he asked, it's probably still visible.

Comment: it's still visible there. ( When i try to access it, i get the error, that the movieclip being tried to be accessed must be child of stage). This also means that movieclip is actually removed successfully, but still showing there.

Comment: so maybe its not on stage but inside some MovieClip that stage contains ? You should add trace(stage,parent) in addEventListener(Event.REMOVED , traceFunction);

Answer (score 1):

From the other question you've asked I gather you are dragging MovieClip instances to the stage in the Flash IDE.  These are never added directly to the stage, but rather to a MainTimeline MovieClip/Sprite, which is itself then added to the stage.

```
stage
  |
MainTimeline
  |
your_mc
```

The stage "contains" only its direct children, i.e. the MainTimeline object, but not the children's children.  `stage.contains (your_mc)` will therefore always return `false`, even if you can still see the MovieClip (and it is, in fact, still in the display list).

Try `DisplayObjectContainer(stage.getChildAt(0)).contains(your_mc)` and see if the result is still `false`...

Comment: comment deleted-------------------

Comment: Actually i am using addChild in my code ( Addiny dynamically, not at authoring time). But anyways thanks for taking time to go through my other post. :)

Comment: Then it's probably not `stage.addChild()`, but `this.addChild()` you are calling, am I correct?

Comment: it's stage.addChild(). And good news is, i figured out that's it error done by me. I am storing the result of stage.addChild() and then removing it in another module.. and again adding it in some other module. I am using puremvc, it's quite a big framework and chain of modules connected with another.. and hence got confused and thus the error. Anyways.. Thanks to all for the help.